# How to Implement Load more Json Using Volley android

Tags: android, scrollview

I have Recyclerview and Scrollview outside the recyclerview

I want o know how to check if scrollview is scroll to the last(bottom).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just scrolling then you can use to NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView So you can modify your code with following :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        //design your content here with RecyclerView 

  </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Also Refer This Link....https://github.com/amardeshbd/android-recycler-view-wrap-content